# How to use rewrite rule or rewrite endpoint to switch languages?

Tags: rewrite-rules, multi-language

The goal is to have this working:

www.pageurl.de -> nothing happens

www.pageurl.de/en/ -> a variable is set and stored in a cookie

this also need to work with permalinks, categories etc. like this:

www.pageurl.de/en/linktopost/

www.pageurl.de/en/categoryname/

i tried to work with
`add_rewrite_endpoint('en',EP_PERMALINK|EP_PAGES|EP_ROOT|EP_CATEGORIES);`

but the endpoint (that makes sense) only works at the end of the url

i also tried to work with

`$language="en";
 add_rewrite_rule('^' . $language . '/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?lang=$matches[1]', 'top');`

but www.pageurl.de/en/ only returns a 404

What is the best way to do this?

I need to have the language pattern in the url on the whole page, lets say after changing the page in a menu the "en" has to be in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this by just adding a rewrite rule, you need to change every recorded rules.

Here is a simple way to do this:

```
function my_rewrite_rules($rules) {

    $new_rules = array();

    $new_rules['(?:de|en)/?$'] = 'index.php';

    foreach ($rules as $key => $val) {

        $key = '(?:de|en)/?' . $key;

        $new_rules[$key] = $val;

    }

    return $new_rules;
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'my_rewrite_rules', 11);
```

Now you still need a way to receipt the language value in order to save it in a cookie.

You could add a parameter for the language, in order to get it inside the `$_GET` super global. But that would means to offset all other parameters of all other rules, and this would involve a lot of regex.

Instead you can simply get the language by querying the `$_SERVER` global:

```
preg_match('/\/(de|en)(\/|$|\?|#)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
```

Comment: thanks alot, that is great, now i set a cookie with the value from the regex.
Do you know how it is possible to have the language paramter ("/en/") in the url on the whole page? How to add the parameter to every link an the page? Thank you very much!

Comment: For this you can add a filter to "home_url" (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/home_url/) and append the language slug to the returned url.

Comment: wow, thanks alot, that is a great hint! one more problem: the rewrite rules are working for the index and for pages but not for custom post type posts, links give a 404, do you know why?

Comment: i think i could fix it by ` $key = '(?:de|en/)?' . $key; ` changing to `$key = '(?:de|en)/?' . $key;`

Comment: next issue: the `home_url`filter is only modifying permalinks but not  `echo(home_ur)l` or `get_bloginfo('url')` I dont understand why

Comment: Of course, sorry for this mistake. I corrected it in my response. `get_bloginfo` don't call the `home_url` filter, that's why. But using `echo home_url()` should do it...

Comment: To make this very clever solution actually work, you'll have to strip leading `^` from the existing rules, like this (in the foreach-loop): `$key = '(?:de|en)/?' . ltrim($key, '^');`

Comment: great simple code thank you! basically it works for me as well but i need to drop the language parameter for the default language like this. "site.com/page" should show the same site like "site.com/fr/page" and "site.com/es/page". how can i achieve this please?

Comment: seems this works (the order is important!) for me:
`foreach ($rules as $key => $val) { $new_key = '(?:de)/?' . ltrim($key, '^'); $new_rules[$new_key] = $val; $new_rules[$key] = $val; }`